# Function composition and the identity function.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

> Define f to be a function whose domain is $X$ and whose target is $Y$ such that $X ∩ Y = ∅$. For each of the following functions, indicate whether the function is well-defined. If your answer is "well-defined", indicate how the function relates to f.

(a) $f \circ I_X$: well-defined because $f(X ->X)$ maps all elements in X to X

(b) $f \circ I_Y$: well-defined because $f(X ->X)$ maps all elements in Y to Y

(c) $I_X \circ f$: how would this work?

(d) $I_Y \circ f$: how would this work

I'm not really sure if my reasoning is correct for the first two. My understanding of the identity function $I_X$ is that it means $X->X$ for all elements in $X$? Is that correct, and are the answers above correct? I also don't know how to interpret and approach c and d, any help or explanation is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ maps elements from $X$ to $Y$. So:

$f \circ I_X$ works: you first take an element of $X$, map it to itself (so you still have an element from $X$), and then apply function $f$ on it which maps element from $X$ to $Y$

However, $f \circ I_Y$ does not work: you first map an element from $Y$ to itself ... and then what? $f$ is not defined for elements of $Y$.

I think you can now also see which of the other two works and which does not work.

Comment: So for c, I would take the function $X->Y$ and then  apply the identity $X$ which maps to itself and gives me an element of X, therefore it doesn't work since it needs to map to a Y?

Comment: @asdfghjkl No!  Read what you just said: you first apply the function $f$ on some element of $X$ and thus obtain an element from $Y$ ... so you can *not* then apply $I_X$ to it, since that new element is not from $X$